# How to add a switch on the notification panel

Tags: android

I do not find how to add a button / switch in the notification panel.
I saw that Spotify add one to switch between online and offline mode, so I guess it's possible.

Thanks

[image: Screenshot of notification pannel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ability appeared in Android 7.0 (API level 24+).
To create you own quick settings tile, you need to create the Java class extending `TileService` class and declare it in `AndroidManifest.xml` with permission `android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE`.

**MyTileService.class**

```
public class MyTileService extends TileService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyTileService";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTileAdded() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onTileAdded()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTileRemoved() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onTileRemoved()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartListening() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartListening()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopListening() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStopListening()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick()");
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
...

<service
    android:name=".MyTileService"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_tray"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

...
```

You can read about callbacks of the `TileService` class in the comments for each method within the base class or [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/TileService.html).